# How to check battery status when acpi is off?

Tags: battery, acpi

I got acpi turned off with the kernel parameter acpi=off. But now I cannot see my battery state in any way. Is there a way to check battery state when acpi is still off?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. ACPI provides the *Power Interface* to your OS.

If you disable that you will lose a lot more power related functionality like suspend. There may be other interfaces to hardware controllers for batteries without relying on ACPI, but I don't know of them.

I recommend not to disable ACPI but try to solve your problem. On a laptop (I assume you are) you really can't work normally without ACPI support. Try to ask another question regarding the reason for why you `acpi=off` solves your problem.